# How to remove a consumer group member in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to remove a group member from a consumer group in Kafka without having to delete the entire group?

Answer (score 1):

If you stop the consumer it will automatically be excluded from the group. If you need it to be part of another group, just assign it a new group id and you're good to go!

Comment: This assumes you have access to stop that member

Comment: The consumer was manually stopped from the console back it seems that is still active for whatever reason.